# Python program executed via "$ python project.py <string> <array>"

Tags: python-3.x

I can't figur out what that exctly means/ how i have to write a program to work when executed that way ("$ python project.py  "). Thanks for helping out a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

This form simply calls the python interpreter (`python`) explicitly, and then passes the script as the first argument. This is mostly equivalent to:

```
$ project.py <string> <array>
```

...but calling the interpreter explicitly will work even if the script is not marked as executable or doesn't have the interpreter defined at the top of the file (e.g. `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/env python`).

If you're being asked to call your script in the `python project.py` form, you don't have to do anything special.